# react-tsparticles, background darkmode

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm working on `background` with `react-tsparticles`.
I have a problem displaying this one,
the whole code looks error free to me, but when displaying I have a flickering effect (particles appear and disappear).
I want to particles switching color after selecting darkmode button

Here is my `Background.js`

```js
import ParticlesConfig from "./ParticlesConfig";
import { useCallback } from 'react';
import { loadFull } from 'tsparticles';
import Particles from 'react-tsparticles';
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";


const Background = (props) => {
  const [theme, setTheme] = useState("light");
  const particlesInit = useCallback(async (engine) => {
    console.log(engine);
    // you can initiate the tsParticles instance (engine) here, adding custom shapes or presets
    // this loads the tsparticles package bundle, it's the easiest method for getting everything ready
    // starting from v2 you can add only the features you need reducing the bundle size
    await loadFull(engine);
  }, []);
  const [particlesContainer, setParticlesContainer] = useState();

  const particlesLoaded = (container) => {
    setParticlesContainer(container);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (particlesContainer && particlesContainer.currentTheme !== props.theme) {
      particlesContainer.loadTheme(props.theme);
    }
  }, [props.theme, particlesContainer]);
  ;
  return (
    <div id='particle-background'>
     
    
    <div className="background">
    <button onClick={() => setTheme("light")}>Light</button>
  
    <button onClick={() => setTheme("dark")}>Dark</button>
    <Particles theme={theme}
     id='tsparticles'
     particlesLoaded='particlesLoaded'
     init={particlesInit}
     loaded={particlesLoaded}
     options={ParticlesConfig}
      />
    
  </div>
  </div>
  );
};

export default Background;
```

here is my `ParticlesConfig.js`

```js
const ParticlesConfig = {
  autoplay: true,
  fullScreen: {
    enable: true,
    zIndex: 0,
  },
  background: {
    color: {
      value: "transparent"
    }
  },
  fpsLimit: 60,
  interactivity: {
    detect_on: 'window',
    events: {
      onClick: {
        enable: true,
        mode: "push"
      },
      onHover: {
        enable: true,
        mode: "repulse"
      },
      resize: true
    },
    modes: {
      bubble: {
        distance: 400,
        duration: 2,
        opacity: 0.8,
        size: 40
      },
      push: {
        quantity: 1
      },
      repulse: {
        distance: 200,
        duration: 0.4
      }
    }
  },
  particles: {
    color: {
      value: "#777"
    },
    links: {
      color: "#777777",
      distance: 150,
      enable: true,
      opacity: 0.5,
      width: 1
    },
    collisions: {
      enable: true
    },
    move: {
      direction: "none",
      enable: true,
      outMode: "bounce",
      random: false,
      speed: 1,
      straight: false
    },
    number: {
      density: {
        enable: true,
        area: 800
      },
      value: 90
    },
    opacity: {
      value: 0.5
    },
    shape: {
      type: "circle"
    },
    size: {
      random: true,
      value: 5
    }
  },
  themes: [
    {
      name: "light",
      default: {
        value: true,
        mode: "light"
      },
      options: {
        background: {
          color: "#0f0e17"
        },
        particles: {
          color: {
            value: "#ff8906"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      name: "dark",
      default: {
        value: true,
        mode: "dark"
      },
      options: {
        background: {
          color: "transparent"
        },
        particles: {
          color: {
            value: "#ff8906"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  detectRetina: true


};
export default ParticlesConfig;
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues in your code, you can see a working sample here: https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-artem-mbfryn?file=/src/Background.jsx

The two issues are:

1. Using `props.theme` but you are setting it in the state, you can get rid of every `props.theme` using `theme` instead, if you want it as a property you can assign it to state instead of the default value you chose
2. Not using the `useCallback` for the `particlesLoaded` function. That function is responsible of the flickering of the background. In the sample I've used a `useCallback` with empty dependencies array since they are not required, and it stopped flickering.

I've also changed the `zIndex` property in the `fullScreen` sections of your particles configuration for showing the theme buttons, and changed particles color just for seeing a difference other than the background.

Comment: @Doodzy could you make the answer as solution, if it's correct? Thanks